# Expression to get a percentage

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report which has a transaction type as a row group. There are two different types. I want to get the percentage of one type 2 compared to type 1.

I am not sure how to do this, I assume I need to use an expression which states the name of the transaction type and then make a calculation based on the other type.

[image]

So Instead of a total for July being 300, I would like the percentage of SOP+ compared to SOP-, so in this case 1.96%. For clarity, the figures in SOP+ are not treated as negative.

Comment: The math is: (SOP+/SOP-1) * 100 if that is what you are looking for

Comment: @sniperd I know the math, just not how to write the expression.

Comment: your problem could be int/int = int

Comment: It depends on how your data is structured in the results of the dataset. Are these values in the same column as they appear on the report or are they actually in two separate columns?

Comment: @StevenWhite they are referenced in the same column on the design page, as they are in a transaction type group. Can i not write an expression where transaction type equals SOP+ then divide by SOP-?

Answer (score 1):

When you design a query to be used in a report, it is generally easier to work with different types of values being in separate columns. You can let the report do most of the grouping and aggregation for you. In that case, the expression would be something like this:

```
=Fields!SOP_PLUS.Value / Fields!SOP_MINUS.Value
```

Since they are both in rows in the same column, you have to use some logic to separate them out into columns and then do the operation.

You'll need to add two calculated fields to your dataset. Use an expression like this to get the values:

```
=IIf(Fields!TYPE_CODE.Value = "SOP+", Fields!SOP.Value, Nothing)
```

In other words, you will have new columns that have just the plus and minus values with blanks in the other rows. Now you can use a similar expression to earlier to compare them.

```
=Max(Fields!SOP_PLUS.Value) / Max(Fields!SOP_MINUS.Value)
```

Keep in mind that the `Max` function applies to the current group scope. When you add in multiple row and column groups to the mix this can get more complicated. If that becomes an issue, I would suggest looking at rewriting the query to provide these values in separate rows to make the report design easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH table1([sop-], [sop+]) AS (
     SELECT 306, -6
UNION ALL
     SELECT 606, -14)

SELECT(CAST([sop+] AS DECIMAL(5, 2)) / CAST([sop-] AS DECIMAL(5, 2))) * 100.0 FROM table1;
```

Returns :

> -1.960784000
>
> -2.310231000